# how to send get and post request in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to implement get and post request in windows phone 8.1 using c#.

I should be able to read the text in the URL using get request and must post something in return it give your id is set with text I have posted.

This is the code I am using for post request.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient clientOb = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
    Uri connectionUrl = new Uri("http://www.xyz.in/hoo/test.php/");
    //text.Text  = pairs;
    Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    pairs.Add("value1", "Hello");
    pairs.Add("value2", "World!");
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await clientOb.PostAsync(connectionUrl, formContent);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(response.Content.ToString());
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

In the above code it just returns the text on the website.

Comment: What happens and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: this code just return the text on the webpage which is"id is not set" i want to post some text so it should return your id is set and the text i have posted

Comment: You write something about a get request. Where is that?

Comment: Sir i just want to implement get and post request on this url

Comment: terasol.in/hoo/test.php/

Comment: Replace "PostAsync" with "GetAsync"?

Comment: You could share server side code too.

Comment: Did you find a solution?